# How do you make a clickable dropdown menu that pushes rest of content on page

Tags: html, css

I think it was a bit hard to explain what I mean in the title, but pretty much what I want to do is to have a text saying "View guild members", and whenever you press on this text, a list of all members fades in.

Thing is though, I have done research and found dropdown menus, but I don't want it to show the content over the content that are displayed.

Easier to explain with these two pictures:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, after pressing the button, the content (link 1-3) displays over "hello". I want to push "hello" further down the page.

How do I do this?

Comment: If you show your css and html, we're more likely to be able to help.  Without seeing it, I would say try setting the dropdown menu css position attribute to relative.

Comment: yea, that worked! :) Is there ways to make it transition in css? or do I need to use jquery for that?

Comment: html: https://pastebin.com/XWMa7tmg css: https://pastebin.com/P6igrhjB

Comment: You can use pure css, either via a transition or via keyframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to accomplish the fade-in animation you need to add these styles in your css:

```
.show {
  display: block;
  animation: fadeIn 600ms ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Here is also a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/QWyLgrg?editors=1111) to play around with the code.